# Adding class to elements over some period of time

Tags: jquery, css

maybe an odd question but is there a way to add a class to multiple elements, one by one over some period of time? For example if I have a paragraph which contains 7 spans with one letter in each....and CSS file with class .up:

```
.up {
position: relative;
animation: goUP 1s linear 0s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite
}

@keyframes goUP{

0%, 100% { 
top: 0px
}

50% {
top: -12px

 }
}
```

is there some way to set interval for 7sec and each second add the class .up to one of the element? I tried for-cyclus, setInterval but nothing works. I'm still learning so don't be too rough on me :).

Comment: How about javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you want just the jquery mode to do that, but here is a solution with pure javascript:

```
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
<p id="paragraph">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
    <span>c</span>
    <span>d</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>f</span>
    <span>g</span>
</p>
<script>
    var p = document.getElementById("paragraph");
    var spans = p.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var seconds = 7;
    var index = 0;

    function timeout() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            // create a recursive loop util all elements.
            if(index < spans.length) {
                spans[index].className += "up";
                console.log(spans[index].className);
                index ++;
                timeout();
            }
        }, seconds * 1000);
    }

    timeout();

</script>
</body>
```

You can adapt it to you code anyway.